# Join multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, natural-join

I have three tables

```
sem1
--------------------------
roll | sub1 | sub2 | gpa |
--------------------------
001  | 98   | 99   | 8.5 |
002  | 99   |100   | 9.9 |
--------------------------

sem2
--------------------------
roll | sub3 | sub4 | gpa |
--------------------------
001  | 88   | 87   | 8.1 |
002  | 89   | 90   | 9.0 |
-------------------------- 

sem3
--------------------------
roll | sub5 | sub6 | gpa |
--------------------------
001  | 85   | 75   | 8.5 |
002  | 90   | 80   | 8.9 |
--------------------------
```

I want to fetch only the roll and gpa columns in all three tables of a particular roll number(say 001) like this.

```
-------------------------
|roll | gpa | gpa |gpa  |
-------------------------
| 001 | 8.5 | 8.1 | 8.5 |
-------------------------
```

I wrote the following query

```
select roll,gpa,gpa,gpa 
    from sem1 natural 
    join sem2 natural 
    join sem3 
    where roll=001;
```

But it doesn't seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Start by revising your schema.. You should have 1 table instead of 3... (student,semester,subject,gpa)

Comment: Don't use natural joins (ever) use specific left joins

Answer (score 1):

With a natural join you have to have a unique column in every table - you don't , gpa is the same so the natural join is on roll and gpa an because gpa differs you get nothing.

if you tables looked like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SEM1,SEM2,SEM3;
CREATE TABLE SEM1(roll INT primary key, sub1 INT, sub2 INT, gpa DECIMAL(10,2));
CREATE TABLE SEM2(roll INT primary key, sub3 INT, sub4 INT, gpa2 DECIMAL(10,2));
CREATE TABLE SEM3(roll INT primary key, sub5 INT, sub6 INT, gpa3 DECIMAL(10,2));

INSERT INTO sem1 VALUES
(001  , 98   , 99   , 8.5 ),
(002  , 99   ,100   , 9.9 );

INSERT INTO sem2 VALUES
(001  , 88   , 87   , 8.1 ),
(002  , 89   , 90   , 9.0 );

INSERT INTO sem3 VALUES
(001  , 85   , 75   , 8.5 ),
(002  , 90   , 80   , 8.9 );
```

Then your query (as amended) would produce a result -

```
select roll,gpa,gpa2,gpa3 
    from sem1 natural 
    join sem2 natural 
    join sem3 
    where roll=001;

+------+------+------+------+
| roll | gpa  | gpa2 | gpa3 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | 8.50 | 8.10 | 8.50 |
+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

For clarity it is best practice to qualify your column names for example

```
select SEM1.roll,SEM1.gpa,SEM2.gpa2,SEM3.gpa3 
from sem1 
natural join sem2 
natural join sem3 
where SEM1.roll=001;
```

But don't use a natural joins use a left joins for example

```
select SEM1.roll,SEM1.gpa,SEM2.gpa2,SEM3.gpa3 
from sem1 
left join sem2 on sem1.roll = sem2.roll
left join sem3 on sem1.roll = sem3.roll
where SEM1.roll=001;
```

but even this is not sufficiently robust in my view relying as it does on sem1 driving and always containing all the distinct roll numbers contained in sem2 and sem3. A more ribust approach would be to get all the distinct roll numbers from all 3 tables and drive from that.